# How to take child content in middle with "line-height"?

Tags: html, css

See my HTMl and I need some help :

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.parent{position:absolute; height:50px; width:120px; background:green}
.child{background:red; width:15px; height:15px; }
```

Now I want take child content in middle. But parent is set with absolute, so it cannot work with line-height. Thanks for your help.

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rHrK3/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your `.child` divider by default is set to display as a block-level element and is thus unaffected by `line-height`.

To resolve this, simply set your `.child` to display as `inline-block` and give your `.parent` a `line-height` equal to its height (50px):

```css
.parent {
    ...
    line-height: 50px;
}

.child {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: Example]

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/rHrK3/4/).

---

*Extra: If you then want to centralize the `.child` divider, you'd simply give your `.parent` a `text-align` of `center` ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/rHrK3/6/)).*

***Edit:*** If you want to place text within your `.child` divider you'll need to give that its own `line-height` to match its height (of 15px).

Comment: it is not working when you put content to child. look at this :http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/rHrK3/7/

Comment: @Mohsen to fix this simply change the `line-height` of the `.child` divider to 15px (to match its height). The question doesn't specify anything about there being text in that element.

Comment: @happi no worries, please remember to set this as the accepted answer when you get the chance! :-)